# Find the row that most frequently contains the largest value in a given column

Tags: r, matrix

Apologies for a potentially suboptimal title - I can't seem to come up with a better one.

Say I have a 3x5 matrix like so:

```
test.df <- matrix(rep(1:5, 3), nrow = 3)
test.df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    2    5    3
[2,]    2    5    3    1    4
[3,]    3    1    4    2    5
```

I would like to return the index of the row that most frequently has the largest value in each of the columns. I can do it combining `which.max`, `apply` and `table` like so:

```
which.max(
    table(
        apply(test.df, 2, which.max)
        )
    )
```

First I apply `which.max` to every column:

```
apply(test.df, 2, which.max)
[1] 3 2 3 1 3
```

Then I apply `table` to the resulting vector and get a tally of how many times a given row was found to have the largest value.

```
table(
    apply(test.df, 2, which.max)
)
1 2 3 
1 1 3
```

Finally, I use `which.max` again to get the index of the row that has the largest value most times.

Unfortunately I need to perform the above operation on about 20000 matrices and some of those can contain many thousands rows. So I wonder if there is a **faster and / or more elegant solution**. Preferably something utilising the power of matrix operations in R.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid looping over columns (i.e., `apply`) by `max.col` in base R:

```
which.max(table(max.col(t(test.df))))
```

Comment: OR `which.max(tabulate(max.col(t(test.df))))`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! According to the benchmark on 1000x15 matrix this approach runs faster than either the original version or the improvement suggested by Marius. I also like the `tabulate` suggestion. The table function unfortunately only reports the cases it sees. So the code has to be messier to ensure the right index is returned.

Answer (score 2):

This solution using `rowSums` seems to provide a pretty good speedup:

```
test.df <- matrix(rep(1:5, 3), nrow = 3)

original = function(m) {
    which.max(
        table(
            apply(m, 2, which.max)
        )
    )
}

row_sums = function(m) {
    which.max(rowSums(apply(m, 2, function(x) {x == max(x)})))
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(original(test.df), row_sums(test.df))
```

Timing results:

```
Unit: microseconds
              expr    min      lq      mean median     uq      max neval
 original(test.df) 86.725 91.6320 107.19399 92.513 94.462 1376.445   100
 row_sums(test.df) 26.698 28.0895  54.30694 29.741 32.443 2378.536   100
```

Comment: It's a good idea to run a benchmark but with such a tiny matrix, the results are not reliable / informative

Comment: Yes, I did bump it up to 100 rows in my initial testing and it seemed to hold up, but going up to 10000+ it seems this might end up being slower than the original.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I thought of rowSums myself, but not quite in this way. It is quite a speedup. At least at about 1000 rows. Thank you!

Comment: In my brief benchmarks I found OP's approach to be fastest, then mine (now deleted) and then Marius', with data sizes around 100k rows and 100 columns